# how-to create a strategy to check in last 5 candlestick if the sequence is buy, sell, sell, buy, sell and last sell breaksout the previously buy

Tags: mt4

I am trying to create a simple strategy for mt4 to check if the sequence of candlesticks are:
buy, sell, sell, buy, sell and the last sell candlestick breaksout the previously buy candle but it is not working.

```
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_color1 Red
#property indicator_color2 Aqua

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  int init()  {
  

         SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_ARROW,STYLE_SOLID,1);
         SetIndexStyle(1,DRAW_ARROW,STYLE_SOLID,1);
         SetIndexArrow(1,233);
         SetIndexArrow(0,234);

         ///
         return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  int start() {
   int counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
   int k,i,j,limit,hhb,llb;

   if (counted_bars<0) return(-1);
   if (counted_bars>0) counted_bars--;
   limit=Bars-1;
   if(counted_bars>=1) limit=Bars-counted_bars-1;
   if (limit<0) limit=0;

     for(i=limit;i>=0;i--)   {
        
     // Verificar se a sequência é "compra, venda, venda, compra, venda"
          if(Close[1]<Open[2] && Close[2] > Open[2] && Close[3] < Close[4] && Close[4] < Open[4] && Close[5] > Open[5]  )

           {
            return(-1);
           }
       }
       return(0);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but does not show the signal for sell in the next candle bearish.